# How can the insights edge be used on the /<page_id>/posts URL with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

So I am trying to retrieve some insights information and noticed there was a connection within the posts field of a page. When I use this connection, it retrieves all of the insights information, all metrics. I only want to limit myself to a few that I need, instead of getting the overhead of searching it out myself after I pick it up.

This is the URL I have tried to limit myself to only the post_consumptions metric

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<page_id>/posts?fields=insights{post_consumptions}
```

This doesn't work, it still returns every metric, so I thought maybe I can't choose the metric, but only the fields. Then I tried this:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<page_id>/posts?fields=insights{id, name}
```

But there were no changes in results, I can't seem to find any documentation about this connection either in the documentation of Facebook Graph API, which doesn't really surprise me as Facebook does this quite a lot.

The documentation about it, which I could find, are here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post#edges

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if you still have this problem but i solved it like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<page_id>/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique)
```

Comment: This is not a link - it is an API